# Targeting addClass to animate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using AOS-Animate (https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) which is great! So I am trying to target to start another animation, once aos-animate has been added to the div.

I want to animate my h2, so each letter animates in a colour.

```js
$('h2').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});

$('.aos-animate h2 span').each(function(i) {
  var row = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    row.toggleClass('anihead');
  }, 40 * i);
});
```

```css
h2 span {
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #202121;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
}

.anihead {
  color: #000;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>This is my header</h2>
```

Could someone please advise how I can target a class that has already been added by another function?

Thank you!

Comment: _"how I can target a class that has already been added by another function?"_ - I don't understand what you mean by that. Who has added what where? For `$('.aos-animate h2 span')` to find anything, an _ancestor_ element of the `h2` would have to have the class `aos-animate` - is that the case?

Comment: so when the div is in screen, .aos-animate is added to the div. This is where I want to start animating

Comment: Then you should trigger this based on the events the scroll plugin provides, https://github.com/michalsnik/aos#js-events

Comment: 'when the div is in screen, .aos-animate is added to the div' you mean when the element is visible while scrolling ? this in an entirely different question/problem than the one you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an event listener that starts the animation when the element is scrolled into view. When the class `.aos-animate` is added the function `$('.aos-animate h2 span').each(...);` will not be called again (it was already called at page load).

But you could use the event listener that adds the class `.aos-animate` when the div comes into view. Instead of adding that class you could add your animation code there:

```js
$('h2 span').each(function(i) {
  var row = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    row.toggleClass('anihead');
  }, 40 * i);
});
```

**Working example:** (*with a simple click listener for demonstration*)

```js
$('h2').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});

$('h2').on('click', function() {
  $('h2 span').each(function(i) {
    var row = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      row.toggleClass('anihead');
    }, 40 * i);
  });
});
```

```css
h2 span {
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #202121;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
}

.anihead {
  color: #000;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>This is my header</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aos is a css and js library, it provides attributes for animating on scroll. If you want to animate an element after it has appeared on the screen you can use their [js events](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos#js-events) to do so.

```js
AOS.init();

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

document.addEventListener('aos:in', ({ detail }) => {

  if (detail == container) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      text.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    }, 1000 /*equals to data-aos-duration*/);
    
  }
});
```

```css
.scroll-down, .scroll-up {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-up p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
}

.text {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="scroll-down"><p>Scroll down</p></div>

<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" class="container">
  <span class="text">Fading in...</span>
</div>

<div class="scroll-up"><p>Scroll up</p></div>
```